# Autoloader при написании бандла для Symfony2 через composer при добавлении нового файла

Tags: composer

### Описание

Пишу свой бандл для `Symfony2`. Создал репозиторий, подключил через `composer` и редактирую его прямо в директории `vendor`, все отлично, но вот новые файлы не хотят подключаться через композеровский `autoloader`.

### Проблема:

Заметил, что `composer` пишет все мои файлы в `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php` и соответственно если туда добавить руками новый файл или сделать `composer update -o` то все отлично. Но постоянно напрягает руками добавлять.

### Вопрос

Как указать композеру, что у меня `PSR-4` и пусть подключается все файлы автоматом, а не статично сохранять в `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`?

Вот `autoload` в `composer.json` проекта:

```
...
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/"
    }
},
...
```

А вот `autoload` в `composer.json` бандла

```
...
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "NameSpace\\MyBundle\\": "../" }
}
...
```

При чем в `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php` мой бандл есть, но видимо настройки кривые, потому что у меня в бандле нет директории `src`:

```
...
'NameSpace\\ MyBundle\\' => array($vendorDir . '/namespace'),
    '' => array($baseDir . '/src'),
...
```

Comment: добавьте бандл в рутовый composer.json как зависимость

Comment: @Etki само сабой )) Проблема то не в этом

Comment: я имею в виду, либо не используйте оптимизацию при построении автолоадера, либо ссылайтесь не на внешний репозиторий, а на локальную папку

Comment: @Etki то есть это все из-за оптимизации автолоадера?

Comment: да, оптимизация значит сдампить все пути к файлам в массив и не использовать динамическое разрешение имени класса

Comment: @Etki а без оптимизации фатальная ошибка "Class ... not found", то есть не подключается нормально мой бандл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге проблема решилась изменением файла `composer.json` в своей библиотеки:

```
...
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "NameSpace\\MyBundle\\": "" }
}
...
```

Изначально путь был указан как `../`, а оказалось достаточно пустую строку прописать.

Теперь обычный `composer update` дает желаемый результат.